# JSON object shows as Null. Why?

Tags: c#, json

This is the class Database:

```
namespace vVvBot.Model
{
    public class Database
    {
        public List<CustomCommand> CustomCommands { get; set; }
        public List<CustomEvent> CustomEvents { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the class for CustomEvent:

```
namespace vVvBot.Model
{
    public class CustomEvent
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public List<CustomCommand> Commands { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the class CustomCommand:

```
namespace vVvBot.Model
{
    public class CustomCommand
    {
        public string Keyword { get; set; }
        public CommandType Type { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the class where I deserialize and serialize the Database object

```
namespace vVvBot.Data
{
    public class FileJsonContext
    {
        public Database ReadToObject(string fileName)
        {
            dynamic jsonData = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Database>(jsonData) ?? new Database();
        }

        public void ObjectToFile(string fileName, Database database)
        {
            dynamic jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(database, Formatting.Indented);

            File.WriteAllText(fileName, jsonData);
        }
    }
}
```

In the file with the issue, this is where I instantiate Database:

```
private Database _database;
public Database Database => _database ?? (_database = JsonContext.ReadToObject("Commands.txt"));
```

The line with the issue is:

```
var messageindex = Database.CustomEvents[index].Commands.FindLastIndex(x => x.Type == CommandType.Welcome);
```

It tries to complete the line but immediately returns because its comes back with null. There is a List in the custom events that should call the customcommand list so I can access the object. Not sure why it comes back to NULL.

The Json File includes:

```
{
  "CustomCommands": [
    {
      "Keyword": "Hello",
      "Type": 0,
      "Message": "World",
      "Enabled": true
    },
    {
      "Keyword": "Test",
      "Type": 0,
      "Message": "test",
      "Enabled": true
    },
    {
      "Keyword": "greeting",
      "Type": 3,
      "Message": "this isnt a test ",
      "Enabled": true
    },
    {
      "Keyword": "leaving",
      "Type": 4,
      "Message": "Sorry to see you go ",
      "Enabled": true
    },
    {
      "Keyword": "faq",
      "Type": 1,
      "Message": "This is a FAQ TEST ",
      "Enabled": true
    },
    {
      "Keyword": "Hi",
      "Type": 0,
      "Message": "Hilo ",
      "Enabled": false
    },
    {
      "Keyword": "Hi",
      "Type": 0,
      "Message": "Hilo ",
      "Enabled": false
    }
  ],
  "CustomEvents": [
    {
      "Name": "greeting",
      "Enabled": true
    },
    {
      "Name": "leaving",
      "Enabled": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: In the JSON string you shared, items of "CustomEvents" do not have property "Commands" set. So when you deserialize, none of the custom events will have commands. It will be empty list so when you query empty list you will always get NULL.

Comment: Does it Not pull all the items from CustomCommands? When Calling it in the CustomEvents class @ChetanRanpariya
Im wanting to use the values that are Already in the CustomCommands

Comment: It does not work that way.... JSON deserialization would not initialize properties based on other properties. It does it based on what values are there in JSON string. Here `Database` object will have `CustomCommands` and `CustomEvents` properties with values but items of `CustomEvents` will not have values in  `CustomCommands` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had this problem a long time ago and i thought the problem was from Unicode.
so i wrote a function for this . you can use it :

```
    List<T> ToJson<T>(byte[] byteArray) where T : new()
    {

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);


    JsonSerializer se = new JsonSerializer();

    StreamReader re = new StreamReader(stream);
    JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(re);
        return se.Deserialize<List<T>>(reader);
     }
```

and i use this function Like this:
    ToJson(data.ToArray());

data is a MemoryStream.

Comment: I am curious about how does this solve the problem of properties not being initialized when property data is not there in JSON string at all. Or I did not understand the problem at all?